# Causes of Cronjob failure in Apache environment

Tags: linux, cron

I'm trying to run a cron job in an Apache Linux environment.
Specifically, this is the cron job.

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin
* * * * * sh root/rsync.sh
```

The rsync in question should synchronize several folders mounted on the Apache, run a single Python script, and copy that result to a new file. I've tested that the rsync works extensively, so I feel sure that the only issues are with the cron job.
It looks mostly like this: (edited for privacy)

```
if [ -e rsyncjob.lock ]
then
  echo "Rsync job already running...exiting"
  exit
fi

touch rsyncjob.lock

#your code in here
cd ..
rsync -r A B
rsync -r C D
python3 <python-file>
rsync <final file>
cd root
#delete lock file at end of your job
rm rsyncjob.lock
```

I keep getting the following error when testing the cron job manually with `cron -f`:

> cron: can't lock /var/run/crond.pid, otherpid may be 23719: Resource temporarily unavailable

Restarting the cron service, and deleting the file listed in the error have both failed.

I've tried different routings but the most common failure is that the rsync source and destination get root appended to the correct location, and then the cron job fails.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: It might not be your current problem, but it is a problem - you need to use absolute paths, both in your cronjob itself and in your script.  Cron's environment is not the same as your shell, and it won't launch in the same place you do.  Both `sh` and `root/rsync.sh` should be fully qualified in your cronjob, eg `/usr/bin/sh /root/rsync.sh`.  Also use full paths to everything in the script: `rsyncjob.lock`, should be `/some/path/to/rsyncjob.lock`, `cd ..` should be `cd /some/other/place` ... same for the python executable `python3`, your actual Python script, `cd root`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your `cron -f` fails because of running system `cron` instance. Stop it `systemctl stop cron` if you are sure about that.

Also avoid using relative paths in cron jobs. for example

```
if [ -e rsyncjob.lock ]
```

should be something like

```
if [ -e /var/<whatever>/rsyncjob.lock ]
```

also fix `cd ..`, `rsync A B` and other relatives.